# php get parameter vs javascripts hash passed to php for session setting

Tags: javascript, php, session, web, hash

everyone 
A very simple question, I'm working on a project web based
The old way I used to direct different articles in my web projects is using
PHP such

```
http://example.php?articleid=1231212321
```

But I wanted to use something like

```
www.mywebsite.com/12312312 instead of 
php?id=232
```

But, the only close solution, I got to this is using hashtag

```
window.location.hash;
```

In case you don't know the above function it get the hashtag from browser header. And thus you can pass it to PHP using JS as well to set session that like

```
    $_SESSION['articleid']="the hashtag"
```

Thus, when you open the page, it fist set the session, then load you the page
Based on the article id

Ex.

```
Web.com/#1231231
```

Where javascript use window location hash and then pass it to  PHP while loading

So, I have two questions

1- is using

```
 window.location.hash
```

with PHP Session, is good practice for this case? And secure?
2- is there any alternative, better practice or approach for my case

I'm not sure what search question to type or words, to get information about this.

So, if any of you need to know why I don't just use

```
PHP?id=1223
```

Because, in my project the user is in index.html
And every button he/she clicks , it load contents into index.html 
So, if the user open an article, the article is loaded into the same

```
 index.html
```

But, then what if he/she want to share the article with another person
Or if want to save it, for later?.

Thus, my solution was, to use

```
Window.Location.hash;
```

Read the hashtag, set the article id in session, load from article based on that session. If no hashtag, then just load the default

Please guide me. I see no problem with my approach.